# Intercept SOAP request

Tags: web-services, soap

I know this might sound like a duplicate but despite the number of result for this research, I couldn't manage to find a working answer..

I'm using a Java Web service built with Axis (the first one), running on Tomcat v5.5 and a .Net client with some Web reference (not the service reference).
What I want to do is to have a look on the outgoing request from my client, the soap enveloppe.

So far, I tried to use soapUI, great tool, helped me a lot for other thing, but the structure of my web service is quite complexe (array of complexe datatypes) so I have no idea on how I could give him some parameters, here is an exemple of the generated request :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://webservices.main.gimaweb.itrec.com" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:televerserDocument soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <wsi xsi:type="urn:DocumentWSI" xmlns:urn="urn:DocumentWS">
            <version xsi:type="xsd:string">?</version>
            <documents xsi:type="doc:ArrayOf_tns1_DocumentWVO" soapenc:arrayType="urn:DocumentWVO[]" xmlns:doc="adress"/>
         </wsi>
      </web:televerserDocument>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But what i need is an array with data, so there is a lot of xml tag missing for that purpose. Maybe there is a way to generate a more complete sample request? (I don't know if I'm clear enough).

I also tried to use Fiddler, also a great tool but I never managed to get the soap enveloppe, I just got the WSDL from when I update the web reference.
I tried different kind of adresses like :

```
localhost:port
localhost.:port
ipv4.fiddler:port
hostname:port
```

But I guess the adress isn't the origin of the problem, I also used ISS Express instead of Visual Studio development server.

Finally, I tried to use some software named Membrane Moniter, but no way to get it, it's becoming quite old, maybe someone knows an alternative

Does someone have a clue on how to do this?

EDIT: And I also tried to use the TCP/IP Monitor on server side, but onece again, I only get the WSDL from the update on VS's side.. I do not really understand why.

EDIT: My Java Webservices are running on Tomcat v5.5, my ASP.Net client is a web application running on IIS Express

Comment: Why are you using a web reference? Use a service reference, then all you need to do is turn on WCF tracing to see the requests and the responses.

Comment: If I use a Service reference, all my generated method are void with no parameters, that does not fit with the real methods. If there is a way to prevent this, I'm ok with that, but I never found one

Comment: Use wireshark, its a bit detailed and intercepts in the packet level, I think you can get what you need.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the software, I'll try it, it seems like a more complete version of fiddler. I'll keep in touch

Comment: Ahah, you have a broken web service that is not WS-I BP-1 compliant. Good luck.

Comment: Where is your Java web service running? You mentioned IIS, but I haven't heard of a Java web service hosted by IIS.

Comment: IIS is for the web client, the Java part run on Tomcat v5.5, I edited the question